# How are the characters connected to the original game in Danganronpa:UDG?

Tags: danganronpa

During Danganronpa: Ultra Despair Girls we are told that the people selected to be *hunted* are related to the characters in the original game.

Some of these are relatively straight forward, but it's been a while since I've played the first game so some links are lost on me.

**How are the new characters related to the old ones?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naegi Komaru -> Younger sister to Naegi Makoto

[image] [image]

Yuta Asahina -> Younger brother of Aoi Asahina

[image]  [image]

Kanon Nakajima -> Manager of Leon Kuwata's Baseball team

[image] [image]

Hiroko Hagakure -> Mother of Yasuhiro Hagakure

[image] [image]

Taichi Fujisaki -> Father of Chihiro Fujisaki

[image] [image]

Ayaka Haneyama -> Member of Sayaka Maizono's idol group

[image] [image]

Grand Bois Chéri Ludenberg -> pet of Celestia Ludenberg

[image] [image]

Takemichi Yukimaru -> leader of Mondo Owada's Biker Gang *Crazy Diamonds*

[image] [image]

Fujiko Yamada -> Older Sister of Hifumi Yamada

[image] [image]

Fuhito Kirigiri -> Grandfather of Kyoko Kirigiri

[image] [image]

Takaaki Ishimaru -> Father of Kiyotaka Ishimaru

[image] [image]

Kameko -> Stinkbug belonging to Toko Fukawa

[image] [image]

Kenshiro -> Sakura Ogami's Love Interest / Rival

[image] [image]

Aloysius Pennyworth -> Butler of Byakuya Togami

[image] [image]

---

**Bonus!**

The following characters were scrapped from the game, but were included in the artbook.

Sayaka Maizono's sister & Chihiro Fujisaki's Mother:

[image] [image]

[source.](http://danganronpa.wikia.com/)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the links can be found if you go on the wiki. The targets were all the most important person to their corresponding character from the first game.
For Example, Hiroko Hagakure is Yasuhiro Hakagure's mother, and Yuta Asahina is Aoi Asahina's brother. But, not all of these figures are human. Celestia Ludenburg's most important person was her cat, and Touko Fukawa's was a bug.